# Split on Regular Expression per Path

Tags: java, regex, string, split

If I have this:

```
thisisgibberish  1234 /hello/world/
more gibberish 43/7 /good/timing/
just onemore    8888  /thanks/mate
```

what would the regular expression inside the Java String.split() method be to obtain the paths  per line?

ie.

```
[0]: /hello/world/
[1]: /good/timing/
[2]: /thanks/mate
```

Doing

```
myString.split("\/[a-zA-Z]")
```

causes the splits to occur to every /h, /w, /g, /t, and /m.

How would I go about writing a regular expression to split it only once per line while only capturing the paths?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you have to `split()`? how about just get match of `/\\S*$` ?

Comment: `/thanks/mate` should there be a "/" at the end of this?

Comment: Can paths contain space or newline characters?  Can an entire line be gibberish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why split ? I think running a match here is better, try the following expression:

```
(?<=\s)(/[a-zA-Z/])+
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sJ2nS7)

Answer (score 0):

This uses `split()` :

```
String[] split = myString.split(myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf(" ")));
```

OR

```
myString.split(myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf(" ")))[1]; //works for current inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first remove the leading junk, then split on the intervening junk:

```
String[] paths = str.replaceAll("^.*? (?=/[a-zA-Z])", "")
    .split("(?m)((?<=[a-zA-Z]/|[a-zA-Z])\\s|^).*? (?=/[a-zA-Z])");
```

One important point here is the use of `(?m)`, which is a switch that turns on "dot matches newline", which is required to split across the newlines.

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "thisisgibberish  1234 /hello/world/\nmore gibberish 43/7 /good/timing/\njust onemore    8888  /thanks/mate";
String[] paths = str.replaceAll("^.*? (?=/[a-zA-Z])", "")
    .split("(?m)((?<=[a-zA-Z]/|[a-zA-Z])\\s|^).*? (?=/[a-zA-Z])");
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( paths));
```

Output (achieving requirements):

```
[/hello/world/, /good/timing/, /thanks/mate]
```